# camelot.ext.ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: -100 while using lattice flavour in camelot

Tags: python, ghostscript, python-camelot

When i try to use lattice flavor in camelot.read_pdf it throws the error
`camelot.ext.ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: -100`
Stream flavor works just fine

Here is my code:

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf("test.pdf", flavor="lattice", pages="7")
tables.export("test.json", f="json")
```

Reason for lattice flavor is that stream flavor is not quite accurate also it is capping at 10 columns which is causing format issues in resulting csv file.

i have tried rolling back ghostscript version i have checked the ghostscript installation using the method given on camelot website - https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html#checks-to-see-if-dependencies-are-installed-correctly
Even tried changing `backend = 'poppler` in read_pdf still same error

Comment: Error code -100 means 'fatal error'; something terminal happened so early that Ghostscript can't even tell you what the problem was. Most probably an illegal parameter or combination of parameters though. Without seeing the input file and command line I can't help you with that. Not the Python or Camelot stuff, the actual file and command line as used to start Ghostscript.